# How to find out what data is collected by Single Sign-On from Google and Facebook?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, google-oauth, facebook-login

Our team is currently trying to better understand what data is collected by Google and Facebook in their implementation of OAuth (“sign-in with Google” and “Login with Facebook”).

Both developers’ docs are extensive on the data that you, as an app or
website developer, can request from the user
(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/ and
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes) but not
much is mentionned about what the platforms collect.

Given that the generated token is renewed everytime a user login we can
assume that each connection is received and potentially stored. But is
there anything else that they could have access to based on their
implementation of OAuth?

We have already used MITMproxy on apps using offering Facebook logins (https://privacyinternational.org/appdata) and could identify some data being sent but it's only limited to Android apps